# Service Missing for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite, dnx

So right now trying to test out the new Visual Studio Code on OS X, but running into a myriad of issues.

Right now been sort out the issue with the dnu command, but now having issues with:
 `dnx . kestrel`

This would be in relation to the **Commands with Ease** section from the [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5) and having the following error message shown in my terminal. So far followed everything step by step and still having issues.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment' has been registered.
      at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService (IServiceProvider provider, System.Type serviceType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService[IApplicationEnvironment] (IServiceProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEngine..ctor (IServiceProvider fallbackServices) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
      at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: For now it seems I'm sorted, untapped and uninstalled the packages available then redid the process.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue when trying to run from the \samples\latest folder instead of \samples\1.0.0-beta4 folder. Simply trying again from where I was supposed to be worked.

Comment: I having the same problem with both folders

Comment: For some odd reason dnx . kestrel decided to work after scaffolding and restoring the NuGet packages, but it seems to be a hit and miss with dnx . web.
Either way, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a runtime version which is still using `IApplicationEnvironment` instead of only `IHostingEnvironment`, than the problem is DNVM can not find the default runtime.

It can be because the runtime is not installed, or Visual Studio is not configured correctly by **global.json** file.

Solution:

- to make sure the targeted runtime version has been installed, type into terminal:
  `dnvm list`
- if the runtime has not been listed (not on the list), install it with
  `dnvm install <runtime> -a <architecture> -r <runtime>`
  *(for example:

  `dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1-update2 -a x64` would install an x64 version of the specified runtime

  or `dnvm install 1.0.0-rc1-update2 -r clr` would install the clr version of the runtime)*
  You can also set the specified runtime as [**default**, **active**, and make your settings **persistent**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110925/how-to-change-default-dnx-version-is-visual-studio-code/33934488#33934488)
- in this phase you can probably run your application from cmd
- in order to be able to run it from Visual Studio, you have to specify the correct runtime version in the **global.json** file, which must be located 2 nodes above the project's folder: *(../GlobalJsonPlace/src/ProjectFolder/..)*
  If you do not have the **global.json** file, create it. It should be something like:

`{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2"
  }
}`

*Note: **src** is the name of the folder, which contains the project's folder.*

- reload your VS instance, and it should be able to run your application.