# How to change default dnx version is Visual Studio Code?

Tags: mono, visual-studio-code, .net-core, coreclr

I am not sure if it is possible but I want to change dnx version when dnx . run from Visual Studio Code.

Even if my current dnx version is *1.0.0-beta5-11682 coreclr* Visual Studio Code runs with *1.0.0-beta4 mono*

Is it possible to change default dnx version of Visual Studio Code?

[image: Some settings]

Answer (score 15):

```
dnvm use VERSION -p
```

where -p is persistent, you can use without it to set version just for the current session.

example

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4
```

or

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4 -p
```

Comment: Even I set like this, when I run dnx: run from VSCode, "_cd /Users/Arda/HelloVSCode ; /Users/Arda/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta5-11735/bin/dnx . run_" it is executed like this. So still mono.1.0.0-beta5-11735 is current dnx version with VSCode

Comment: Yes, it did not help. The interesting thing is when I change the dnx runtime to coreclr, dnx command does not appear in VS Code's command pallette when I restart VSCode

Answer (score 12):

`dnvm use <runtime_version> -r <runtime> -a <architecture> -p`

examples:
`<runtime_version>`: `1.0.0-rc1-update2` etc.
`<runtime>`: `mono`, `clr`, `coreclr` *(optional)*
`<architecture>`: `x64`, `x86` *(optional)*
`-p`: makes the results persistent *(optional)*

Selecting **Active**:

You have to provide the **Runtime** version as well, if there are multiple choices for the same name. For example type the following:

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4 -r mono
```

If you would have to provide **Architecture** as well, the following command would apply:

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-beta4 -r mono -arch <architecture>
```

where  can be "x64" for example, **without the quotes**.

Setting **Default**:

```
dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta5-11682 -r coreclr -arch x64
```

Please note that, there were a bug (about May, 2015), in which referring to a *CoreClr* runtime by alias was not working. I don't know if it's fixed yet, but I guess so. Source: [Issue 175 about the bug](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/175).

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a version in the `global.json` file (like so https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/global.json#L4) or use the combination of `dnvm alias` and `dnvm use`. OmniSharp (the C# brain used by VSCode) will first check the `global.json` file and then go with the default-alias. All the details can be found here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/src/OmniSharp/AspNet5/AspNet5Paths.cs#L45

Comment: I add the global.json with coreclr version. But again when I run dnx:run from vscode, the current execution command like "_cd /Users/Arda/HelloVSCode ; /Users/Arda/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta5-11735/bin/dnx . run_"
I just want to be executed as CoreCLR "_cd /Users/Arda/HelloVSCode ; /Users/Arda/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-darwin-x64.1.0.0-beta5-11735/bin/dnx . run_"

Comment: Please check the OmniSharp log in VSCode (Ctrl+U,L) for what version was picked for your project. For executing commands, VSCode will take that version as well.

Comment: I am running omnisharp-atom, I am getting error message "No default runtime found" I have installed 1.0.0-beta4 as per the README file.  Is Omnisharp-Roslyn installed as part of that, is so where does it reside?

Comment: yeah, there should be a node_module shipping with omnisharp-atom which contains omnisharp roslyn. tho the error is saying that it failed to find a DNX runtime.