# Syntax error not detected when using project.json

Tags: macos, editor, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have two projects setup in vsCode. The one using a project.json file (which is a console app, generated using 'yo aspnet' and choosing the Console Application option) is always displaying "Error: Failed to start OmniSharp" hence am not able to detect syntax errors.

If I open an existing project with a csproj file, everything runs properly. I am really confused now. Thanks

Comment: There seems to be an issue about starting OmniSharp. It would be best to file a bug here https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem...omnisharp not starting in vscode for a aspnet v5 project. For me, the problem was that I had installed the latest dnx (beta7) and omnisharp does not yet support beta7.

To fix, I used dnvm to set the default dnx to a beta-6 version. More information here:

[How to change default dnx version is Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110925/how-to-change-default-dnx-version-is-visual-studio-code)

tl;dr:

`dnvm use 1.0.0-beta6 -r coreclr -arch x64 -p
dnvm alias default 1.0.0-beta6 -r coreclr -arch x64`